# vscode remote environment variables don't match `.bashrc`

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, bashrc, remote-connection

Let's say the `$PATH` variable contained `/usr/bin` before everything.

My `~/.bashrc` used to have a line like this:

```
export PATH='/home/user/123:$PATH'
```

Then, I changed the line to:

```
export PATH='/home/user/789:$PATH'
```

In vscode, to see the effects of the new environment variable, I carelessly ran `bash` in the terminal. Now when I run `echo $PATH`, I'm getting `/home/user/789:/home/user/123:/usr/bin`. It doesn't change if I close the vscode and open again. It's stuck like this.

If I `ssh` to the server and run `echo $PATH,` The result is `/home/user/789:/usr/bin`, which is expected. How can I fix the issue in vscode without having to remove the host from my remote extension settings?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to restart the vscode remote server.

There are two known ways:

1. Disconnect all the existing vscode client and wait for 5min, [because server will wait for 5min until shutdown](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1244#issuecomment-524801497)
2. run `ps uxa | grep .vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` to manually kill vscode process, refered from [this issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5813#issuecomment-958770528)